# Is earning money from twitch haram? This is a very new way of making money?

Tags: sharia

So I am having difficulty understanding if making money on twitch is haram because the system of earning money on twitch is something that didn't happen in the past. On twitch you earn money by getting bits people have purchased and people subscribing to you. Is this way of earning permissible in Islam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earning on streaming is much like other broadcasting systems, the question stays what are you streaming. If your broadcast is in compliance with islam then earning is halal otherwise not.

Comment: Ty for your answer, sry for late reply XD